# How to set new borders with oxyplot forn a UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, get, set, diagram

I got a problem with the borders of my x-axis.
As you can see in the pictures I´m working with a CalenderDatePicker. 
Process: User chooses two dates. As soon as he chooses the dates the borders of the x-axis change and you see a period of time as the new borders.

[image: https://s17.directupload.net/images/190601/ieycbwwb.png]

[image: https://s17.directupload.net/images/190601/4tdufwfq.png]

[image: https://www.directupload.net/file/d/5470/8lj4zp54_png.htm]

Comment: Can you show us a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you check the [oxyplot document](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/common-tasks/refresh-plot.html), you will know how to update the plot.

> To update the plot, you must do one of the following alternatives:
>
> Change the Model property of the PlotView control
> Call Invalidate on the PlotView control
> Call Invalidate on the PlotModel

I've made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
xmlns:oxy="using:OxyPlot.Windows"
```

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding MyModel}" x:Name="oxyplot"/>
    <Button Content="reset" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        oxyplot.Model.Axes[0].Minimum = 20;
        oxyplot.InvalidatePlot();
        oxyplot.Model.InvalidatePlot(true);
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.MyModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Example 1" };
        this.MyModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis() { Minimum = 10, Maximum = 100, Position = AxisPosition.Bottom });
    }

    public PlotModel MyModel { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I found the problem by the way and its much easier than we all thought I think. I used the LinearAxis. I had to use DateTimeAxis. Embarrassing I know . :D

Comment: @Pyllic If my reply help resolve your issue or is helpful to you, you could vote up/ mark it as [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) answer.